# Semi-complicated result set in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a `user` table like this

```
FIRSTNAME  |  LASTNAME  |  ID  |
--------------------------------
James      |  Hay       |  1   |
Other      |  Person    |  2   |
```

I also have an `attendance` table like this

```
EVENTID  |  USERID  |  ATTENDANCE  |  STATUS  |
-----------------------------------------------
1           1          True           3
2           1          False          1
3           1          False          3
1           2          False          1
2           2          True           3
3           2          True           3
```

Basically, when a user is invited to an event, a row is added to the `attendance` table which has the event ID, their user ID, false attendance, and status 0.

Status is just an indicator of their response

```
0 = No Response
1 = Said No
2 = Said Yes
3 = Said yes and seats confirmed
```

My end result I want to get from querying these two tables is quite complicated and I can't figure out what I need to do.

I want to get a result like this

```
NAME          |  % of saying YES to an RSVP  | % of attending after saying yes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
James Hay     |             66               |                50
Other Person  |             66               |                100
```

I'm sure you can work out how I got those numbers but to explain, James Hay had the 3 (yes) status to 2/3 events invited to. So % of saying yes is 66. Out of the 2 he said yes to, he only attended 1/2 so % of attending after saying yes is 50%

Any push in the right track would be much appreciated here since I can't get my head around this.

**EDIT:**

Also something quite important is that I want the results to include every user in the database even if they have 0 rows in the `attendance` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.PERCENTAGE_YES_RSVP,B.PERCENTAGE_AFTER_YES
FROM 
( 
  SELECT U.ID AS ID,U.FIRSTNAME+''+U.LASTNAME AS NAME
  FROM USERS U
) A,
(
  SELECT A.USERID,A.PERCENTAGE_YES_RSVP,B.PERCENTAGE_AFTER_YES
FROM   
  (
    SELECT B.USERID,ROUND((CAST(B.COUNT_YES_RSVP AS FLOAT)/B.TOTAL_COUNT)*100,0) AS PERCENTAGE_YES_RSVP    
    FROM  
    (SELECT A.USERID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.STATUS=3 THEN 1 END)AS COUNT_YES_RSVP,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT
       FROM ATTENDANCE A  
       GROUP BY A.USERID
     ) B
  ) A,  
(
  SELECT C.USERID,(CAST(C.COUNT_AFTER_YES_RSVP AS FLOAT)/C.TOTAL_COUNT)*100 AS PERCENTAGE_AFTER_YES   
  FROM  
  (SELECT A.USERID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.STATUS=3 AND A.ATTENDANCE='TRUE' THEN 1 END)AS COUNT_AFTER_YES_RSVP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.STATUS=3 THEN 1 END) AS TOTAL_COUNT
   FROM ATTENDANCE A  
   GROUP BY A.USERID
   ) C
)B   
WHERE A.USERID=B.USERID
) B
WHERE A.ID = B.USERID;
```

Comment: I get an incorrect syntac near ')' error on the line `SUM(CASE WHEN A.[STATUS]=3 THEN 1)`

Comment: Yup this one is giving me more accurate answers as well (ie decimal places). The only problem is there are 869 users in my DB, I'm only getting 340 rows. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: Thats great... sat on this for the last 30 mins... :)

Comment: Yeah I wanted to get all the people that have never been invited as well but I convinced my boss that it's not going to be useful for our purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select
u.firstname, u.lastname
-- said yes, as percentage
,floor(100.0
    * count(case when a.status in (2,3) then 1 end)
    / count(u.id)) yes
-- attended after saying yes, as percentage
,floor(100.0
    * count(case when a.status in (2,3) and attendance='true' then 1 end)
    / nullif(count(case when a.status in (2,3) then 1 end),0)) attendance
--,count(u.id) rsvp -- total invites
from users u
left join attendance a on a.userid = u.id
group by u.firstname, u.lastname
```

**Note:** For the special case where the user has never received an invite, the statistics show as 0% and NULL.

Explanation of the terms:

- `count(case when a.status in (2,3) then 1 end)`

  - represents how many times they said yes, used twice
- `count(u.id)`

  - how many invites (recorded in attendance) received. Special case is when they have received none, in which case the LEFT JOIN makes it `1` (not important)
- `count(case when a.status in (2,3) and attendance='true' then 1 end)`

  - count of how many times they attended, AFTER having said yes

Comment: Thanks this one worked, and you also explained it to me which is nice and helpful. Just going to check which of these is faster. Cheers

Comment: I thought you wanted whole numbers from your sample. If you wanted decimals, just remove the words "floor" where they occur.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Whoops, forgot to join on users :)

```
select firstname, lastname,
  convert(decimal (5, 2), 1. * count(case when status in (2, 3) then 1 end) / count(*) * 100) SaidYes,
  convert(decimal (5, 2), 1. * count(case when status in (2, 3) and attendance = 'True' then 1 end) / count(case when status in (2, 3) then 1 end) * 100) ActuallyAttended
from attendance a
join users u on a.userid = u.id
group by firstname, lastname
```